# Pure CSS form label is condensed into small space

Tags: html, css

Im very new to html, and Im trying to create a website that uses Pure (type of CSS) forms to make a political poll. The issue I am having is that it scrunches up the question into a narrow spot, making it use several lines, when there is clearly room for it across the page to just take up one line (row). I tried telling the form to give the question (the label part) a certain portion of the page, and the rest of the line for the box where the user enters their answer, but the question (label) remains condensed into a small space. Any help to fix this is appreciated.  Here is the code I am using to try to accomplish this:

```
    <form class="pure-form pure-form-aligned" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" name="myForm" action="politicsInsert.php" >
    <fieldset>

    <div class="pure-control-group">
    <label class="pure-input-2-3" for="answerOne">What is your current political affiliation? </label> <input id="answerOne" type="text" name="answerOne">
    </div>
<input class="pure-button pure-button-primary" type="submit" value="Submit data!">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: this is all I use to create the pure form - I just have a link at the top of the html page:   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.5.0/pure-min.css">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label's width rule in the [CSS you're linking to](http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.5.0/pure-min.css) is causing the text to split over multiple lines:

```
.pure-form-aligned .pure-control-group label {
text-align: right;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 10em;
margin: 0 1em 0 0;
}
```

You can override it via something like:

```
div.pure-control-group label.pure-input-2-3 {
    width:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wDN9d/)**

Comment: After you link to that other stylesheet.

Comment: I do also have a separate CSS style sheet for the page ( it does nothing but set the background of the page) ....so I could include that override int there correct?